# PHP PDO displaying first result only

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to display all the photos which has been uploaded on my website but I can only display the first row data only. Can anyone help me on this.

```
<?php
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM event";
            //$query1 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
            $result = $db->prepare($sql1);
            $result->execute();
            while($albumId = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $ID = $albumId['eventID'];
                $albm = $albumId['eventName'];

                    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE eventID = '$ID'";
                    // $query2 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql2);
                    $result = $db->prepare($sql2);
                    $result->execute();
                    while($photos = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        $cap = $photos['photoName'];
                        $source = $photos['photoPath'];
                    ?>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <?php //echo $cap; ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $source;?>">
                            <?php echo "Photo uploaded to: "."<b>".$albm."</b>"; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                    }  
            }
```

Comment: in second query you used same variable $result change it by $result2 and check..

Comment: ok thanks a lot that worked

Comment: feel happy to help you Happy Coding..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$result = $result->fetchAll();
```